# Kitchen tests with AIX

Tags: chef-infra, aix, test-kitchen

While Chef-Client is supported on AIX I can't find any official kitchen driver for AIX. Is there something or how does the chef/AIX community does Chef Cookbook integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made available a kitchen driver using wpar here : https://github.com/adejoux/kitchen-wpar

One using powervc is on his way too: 
https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/aix/issues/28

Feedbacks and/or contributions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one right now that is public. I'm working on one for Bloomberg but Solaris is coming first and will take another few weeks so watch https://github.com/poise for a WPAR driver plugin.

Comment: Also if you know stuff about AIX I would love to pick your brain about WPAR automation.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds great. We will have a project where we will use chef with AIX and I ask myself if it is a good idea to use Chef on AIX without kitchen. What do you think? Are there other ways to do good integration tests?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053361/kitchen-tests-with-aix/36530095#36530095 . seems there are people who know something about kitchen wpar automation.